# Acceder al contenido de un <iframe> desde el documento padre bajo Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

Estoy haciendo un *scraper*; para ello, necesito acceder al contenido de un `<iframe>` y recorrer sus elementos.

Eso **está prohibido** en página *normales*, así que he decidido usar [`Electron`](https://www.electronjs.org/)(`v25.4.0`), pero, **aun así**, obtengo el error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "file://" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Lo curioso es que la consola me avisa de que la seguridad está deshabilitada:

> Electron Security Warning (Insecure Content-Security-Policy) This renderer process has either no Content Security Policy set or a policy with "unsafe-eval" enabled. This exposes users of this app to unnecessary security risks.

La creación de la ventana del navegador la estoy realizando así:

```
new BrowserWindow( {
    webPreferences: {
        webSecurity: false
    }
} );
```

Se aprecia que estoy pasando el `webSecurity: false`, lo cual es acorde a los avisos que obtengo por consola.

En la página, el acceso al `<iframe>` lo estoy realizando así:

```
async get( ref ) {
    const self = this;

    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
        self._iframe.src = "https://url-a-la-que-intento-acceder/";
        self._iframe.onload = function( ev ) {
            const result = self._iframe.contentWindow.document;

            resolve( result );
        };
    } );
}
```

En ese punto del código, he comprobado que `self._iframe` es correcto; lo obtengo con anterioridad (solo hay 1 `<iframe>` en mi página) mediante un `document.getElementById( )`.

- ¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Como lo soluciono ?

Comment: Seguro que puede accederse al contenido?? En Angular lo intenté de muchas maneras y siempre me acabé dando de bruces contra la seguridad del navegador. Al final da igual qué framework uses, por debajo sigue mandando el motor del navegador. A no ser que tu url actual y la del iframe coincidan, no te va a dejar toquetearlo mucho. Ojalá lo consigas, a ver si puedo luego ver la manera de hacerlo con angular  :)

Comment: El problema es que [la configuración de `webSecurity` no controla CORS desde la versión de Electron 9.0.0 en adelante](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23664#issuecomment-692422997). Prueba usar una versión anterior a ver si funciona. Saludos

Comment: Podrías usar [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) sólo si tuvieras acceso a ambos recursos, pero viendo que se trata de un `scrapping` esta no es una alternativa.

Comment: @Benito-B Electron es un framework que trae su propio navegador, sin depender de nada externo. **Se supone** que puedes *customizar* ese navegador según necesites.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Jo, pues me has *chafado* el invento :-(

Comment: Yo? Es `chromium` y sus cosas. XD

Answer (score 2):

Varias búsquedas en Google mediante, encontré la solución [aquí](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/24044#issuecomment-644095948).

La solución es tan sencilla como añadir un opción a la *línea de órdenes virtual* con la que se ejecuta el navegador:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch( "disable-site-isolation-trials" );
```

De hecho, funciona tan bien que ya no es necesario pasar ninguna configuración adicional al crear la ventana; ni siquiera el `webSecurity: false`. Con lo que el código final para crear la ventana es:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require( "electron" );

function createWindow( ) {
    const win = new BrowserWindow( );

    win.loadFile( "public/index.html" );
}

app.commandLine.appendSwitch( "disable-site-isolation-trials" );

app.whenReady( ).then( function( ) {
    createWindow( );

    app.on( "activate", function( ) {
        if( BrowserWindow.getAllWindows( ).length === 0 ) {
            createWindow( );
        }
      } );
} );
```

Funciona perfectamente con `Electron v25.4.0`. En mi `html`, los errores han desaparecido de la consola, y la función que accede al contenido del `<iframe>` ahora devuelve lo esperado, un `document`.

Comment: Supongo que usas Electrón solamente para solventar el problema, llegado el caso puedes tambien iniciar el navegador de esta manera `msedge.exe --disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="C:\temp"` (o chrome.exe ....) y dará el mismo resultado. También es posible crear un acceso directo con este comando